# Centered Background Image cutoff on Mobile Devices

Tags: css, image, mobile, background, center

So I created a website that is designed to scale to mobile devices

http://follow.sueu.org.au/

It worked fine on my old android phone but doesn't work on more modern smartphones (both Iphone and Android) that use Google Chrome.

The problem is that on the home page the background image is half off the screen on mobile devices.

http://s23.postimg.org/4hozcopsb/photo.png

I'm fairly amateur at CSS and I'm sure there's something simple that I've done wrong, but I can't figure it out.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>The Story of Love</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;">

<style>

    #wrap { 
      width: 500px; 
      margin: 0 auto;
     }

    body
    {
    background-image:url('Images/Title_BackgroundImage.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size:500px;
    background-color:#4e4943;
    }

        .introduction {
        position: top center;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 227px;
        width: 500px;
    }
        .introduction a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .love {
        position: top center;
        top: 227px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 90px;
        width: 500px;
    }
        .love a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .gather {
        position: top center;
        top: 317px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 94px;
        width: 500px;
    }
        .gather a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .relate {
        position: top center;
        top: 411px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 91px;
        width: 500px;
    }
        .relate a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .witness {
        position: top center;
        top: 502px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 79px;
        width: 500px;
    }
        .witness a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .love2 {
        position: top center;
        top: 581px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 125px;
        width: 500px;
    }
        .love2 a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }


@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
    {

    #wrap { 
      width: 320px; 
      margin: 0 auto; 
    }

    body
    {
    background-image:url('Images/Title_BackgroundImage_Mobile.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size:320px;
    }

    .introduction {
        position: top center;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 145px;
        width: 320px;
    }
        .introduction a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .love {
        position: top center;
        top: 145px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 320px;
    }
        .love a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .gather {
        position: top center;
        top: 203px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 60px;
        width: 320px;
    }
        .gather a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .relate {
        position: top center;
        top: 264px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 61px;
        width: 320px;
    }
        .relate a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .witness {
        position: top center;
        top: 323px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 51px;
        width: 320px;
    }
        .witness a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    .love2 {
        position: top center;
        top: 372px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 78px;
        width: 320px;
    }
        .love2 a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">

<div class="introduction">
<a href="Introduction/Introduction.html">
</a></div>

<div class="love">
<a href="Chapter1/Chapter1_Title.html">
</a></div>

<div class="gather">
<a href="Chapter2/Chapter2_Title.html">
</a></div>

<div class="relate">
<a href="Chapter3/Chapter3_Title.html">
</a></div>

<div class="witness">
<a href="Chapter4/Chapter4_Title.html">
</a></div>

<div class="love2">
<a href="Chapter5/Chapter5_Title.html">
</a></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #wrap { 
  width: 500px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

For example on iphone you will see it cutted almost on half cause it have 320px width.
you should add something like that:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
       #wrap { 
        width: 320px!important; 
       }
}
```